# Android: Can't call new activity from class that extends Thread

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Edit: Changed the code to reflect suggested answers...still think I'm missing something

I am running a game in a class that extends Thread and want to be able to call a class that performs graphics at certain times. To do this I am trying to use intent to open the class but cannot get it to work. Here is the code:

NewGameThread.java:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class NewGameThread extends Thread {

private Context context;

public GameView mGameView;

public NewGameThread(GameView gameView, Context context) {      
    mGameView = gameView;
    this.context = context;
}   
}
```

NewTheGame.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class NewTheGame extends NewGameThread {


private Bitmap mBall;
private float mSmileyBallX = -100;
private float mSmileyBallY = -100;

public NewTheGame(GameView gameView) {

    super(gameView);
    //Set up my bitmaps
    mBall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource
            (gameView.getContext().getResources(), 
                    R.drawable.small_red_ball);

}
protected void updateGame(float secondsElapsed) {
    if(mSmileyBallX == mSmileyBallY) { //it actually calls another function that I removed for simplicity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,Launcher.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that code compile? There is no startActivity() method in Thread AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need context of activity class, so you need one constructor in `NewGameThread`

```
Context context;

public NewGameThread(Context context)
{
   this.context = context;
}
```

then in your code you must use this context like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (context, Launcher.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not quite getting it to work though. Would it look like this:

NewGameThread.java
import android.content.Context;

public class NewGameThread extends Thread {
 
 private Context context;
 public GameView mGameView;

 public NewGameThread(GameView gameView, Context context) {  
  mGameView = gameView;
  this.context = context;
 } 
}

Comment: import android.content.Intent;

public class NewTheGame extends NewGameThread {
 
 private Bitmap mBall;
 private float m1 = -100;
 private float m2 = -100;

 public NewTheGame(GameView gameView) {

  super(gameView);
 
 }
 protected void updateGame(float secondsElapsed) {
  if(m1 == m2) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context,Launcher.class);
      context.startActivity(intent);
  }
}

Comment: what is your problem now? please update your question with new info and new problem

Answer (score 1):

The context should be passed in from the activity. When you create the object of class NewGameThread from your Activity, pass context of the activity in constructor. Use that context in the intent call.

```
public class NewGameThread extends Thread {

    public NewGameThread(Context c){
        this.context = c;
    }  

    protected void getActTwo() {        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context,ActivityTwo.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you DO NOT pass in the contact from the activity, and store it in the thread. This means that all the memory with the activity  that started the thread (and it's entire View Hierarchy) cannot be garbage collected until the thread dies and is itself garbage collected. A better solution is to use a reference to the Application context - as it won't have the View hierarchy attached to it - and will continue to be alive anyway.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, so would you recommend doing what shayan mentioned above? I still can't get it to work.